# Mathematical Induction validity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

i was going through Discrete mathematics by Rosen and stuck on below paragraph. I fail to understand the line that is highlighted. How is P(m-1) -> P(m) is true.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true because the author assumed that “the proposition $P(k)\rightarrow P(k+1)$ is true for all positive integers $k$”.

Comment: But isn't 'm' part of set S for which P(n) is false? So P(m) should be false?

Comment: Yes. And that's why we reach a contradiction.